# c# Linq Compare xelement with string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I need to compare `XElement` with string inside foreach , but in does not working for some reason ...

here is my c# code

```
string ID = test;
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(_file);
var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("Root").Elements("user") select c;
int i = 0;
foreach (XElement utilizador in query)
{
    if (i == 0 && utilizador.Attribute("done").Value != "0" && 
                           utilizador.DescendantNodes().ToString().Contains(id))
    {
        utilizador.Attribute("done").Value = "0";
        i++;
    }
}
xmlFile.Save(_file);
```

for some reason I am not aware about `utilizador.DescendantNodes().ToString().Contains(id)` is not working for me 
Thank you.

Comment: "*but in does not working for some reason*" you might want to add some details about what exactly isn't working, what exception you get or what the expected behavior would be. A [mcve] would also be nice.

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: fancy a read : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it does not giving me any exceptions, but it is not changing anything in my xml file , if i remove utilizador.DescendantNodes().ToString().Contains(id) everything works fine, but when i try to see if any descendant node contains  ID it simply not changing anything in my xml file

Comment: I would do it like this : if (i == 0 && (int)utilizador.Attribute("done") != 0 && (string)utilizador.DescendantNodes().Contains(id))
            {
                utilizador.SetAttributeValue("done", 0);
                i++;
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead:

```
utilizador.DescendantNodes().Any(x=>x.Value.Contains(id))
```

Comment: Thank you very much